# Packages to create attractive presentations in LaTeX

Tags: beamer, graphics, presentations

I use the beamer package to create presentations. A sample code is as follows:

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \usetheme{Antibes}
  \title[Demo]{A Sample \LaTeX presentation}
  \author{S.Subham Soni}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \titlepage
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

I want to add my college logo in a corner in all pages and some information (metadata) at the top in all the pages (which will be common) and I want to enhance the design and look.How do I do that.

[image]

Comment: `\logo{}` is the command to specify a logo: for example `\logo{\includegraphics{sedes.pdf}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put

```
\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.45cm]{logo}{pecemblem}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}
```

in the preamble to insert the logo. Enhancing styles needs more work. I suggest you to explore the available themes: [from google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=beamer%20theme%20matrix&oq=beamer%20theme%20matrix&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7793j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) as an immediate remedy. There are themes which put meta data like author name etc in the footline. Please don't put them in the top.

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \usetheme{Antibes}
  \title[Demo]{A Sample \LaTeX\ presentation}
  \author{S.Subham Soni}
  \pgfdeclareimage[height=0.45cm]{logo}{pecemblem}
  \logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \titlepage
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

[image]
Please use `\LaTeX\` or `\LaTeX{}` to preserve the space after the word.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I over looked them. :-)